# How to log instantiation parameters for child class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which I subclass. One of the features of the abstract class is it has an attribute which stores all of the parameters which were input to instantiate the class. For example, the following code achieves my goal:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter):
        pass


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2):
        self.input_params = locals()
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent_parameter)
```

With this code I can access the original input parameters via the `self.input_params` attribute. However, the problem is the first line of code `self.input_params = locals()` must be included in every subclass. I would like some sort of solution like

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter):
        self.input_params = locals()



class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent_parameter)
```

basically such that whoever writes the child class doesn't need to take care to include the code for parameter logging. Of course the code in this block will only capture the `parent_parameter` parameter and none of the child parameters.

The child parameters could of course be explicitly passed through to the parent class `__init__` but this breaks the requirement of the implementer not having to worry about the logging and introduces `*args` and `**kwargs` which feels superfluous.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, *args, **kwargs):
        self.input_params = locals()



class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2)
```

edit:
perhaps best is just documentation of the required code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter):
        # subclass __init__() must begin with `self.input_params = locals()`
        pass


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2):
        self.input_params = locals()
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent_parameter)
```

Comment: Your second block of code probably doesn't give you what you want anyways.  Since the names of the parameters don't exist in the parent implementation, they don't exist in locals() either.  What you get from `locals()` for that case looks like this: `{'self': <__main__.Child object at 0x108492278>, 'parent_parameter': 1, 'args': (2, 3), 'kwargs': {}}` - I've never seen `locals()` used this way. I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: @Steve yes, that is correct. The second block of code does not have the appropriate behavior. It's demonstrating the sort of style I would like the eventual working code to have. That is, all of the logging code is somehow handled in the `Parent` class without the `Child` class having to worry about it. Of course I need code that works, not code that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `locals()` is the correct way to go either. If there's a better way to capture the input parameters (without explicitly listing them all out in the `Child` class which I had been doing previously...) I'm happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to come up with something that works by overriding `__new__`, I think. I would appreciate feedback on if this is unpythonic or hacky or if this is sort of a typically use case for `__new__`.

```
class Parent:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        input_params = {'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs}
        obj = super(Parent, cls).__new__(cls)
        obj.input_params = input_params
        return obj

    def __init__(self, parent_parameter):
        pass


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_parameter, child_parameter_1, child_parameter_2):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent_parameter)
```